# Why does enabling hardware acceleration on parent dom node break position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Enabling hardware acceleration on parent dom nodes breaks `position: fixed`
**why is this?**

this is broken in webkit and firefox

**Reduced test case here**

http://codepen.io/s/pen/yzHFA

---

gpu mode enabled by

```
@include transform(translateZ(0));
@include perspective(1000);
@include backface-visibility(hidden);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for you. This is happening because the CSS 2D transformations create a containing block around the transformed element, causing it to scroll with the document.

For a detailed explanation, see Eric Meyer's post http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/09/12/un-fixing-fixed-elements-with-css-transforms/